# Missing ; before statement, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying something with JavaScript. I keep getting this error for the following code block -

```
"There is a missing ; before statement."
```

And the statement referred to is the for loop after the function `TeamConst`. Any idea why?!

```
function Semis1TieBreakCheck(){

      function TeamConst(TeamName, rd1, rd2, semiscomb){
        this.TeamName = TeamName;
        this.rd1 = rd1;
        this.rd2 = rd2;
        this.semiscomb = semiscomb;
      };

      for(var i = 0; i <= numofTeams-0; i++){
        var team[i] = new TeamConst(values[i+2][5],values[i+2][6],values[i+2][7],values[i+2][6] + values[i+2][7]);
      };

    };
```

Comment: Check the semicolon's after the }

Comment: Remove the semi-colon immediately after your `for {}` loop.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't work still though.

Comment: For me, I mistype `function` as `funtion`(missed a `c` character after `fun`), and then this error occured.

Answer (score 7):

You can't declare a property of an object/array using the `var` keyword.

Change `var team[i] = ...` to just `team[i] = ...`.

Also make sure that team is declared somewhere. If it is not already declared in an outer scope then add this before your loop:

```
var team = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get that error, but there is a different one. You need to define `team` first.

```
var team = [];                                                                                            
for (var i = 0; i <= numofTeams-0; i++) {
   team.push(new TeamConst(values[i+2][5],
                           values[i+2][6],
                           values[i+2][7],
                           values[i+2][6] + values[i+2][7])
            );                                                                                                            
};
```